# The dependents of External Libraries all gone,how to add back?

Tags: android, android-studio

As follows:

[image: The dependents of External Libraries all gone]

I might have deleted what moudle it，project struct As follows:

[image: Only left ‘MyApplication’]

Comment: I do not know why the picture did not show, please click on the blue font. A total of 2 pictures.

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @isnotmenow rebuilt the application, it prompts: Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Comment: there's could be something wrong with your build.gradle or root project gradle.

Answer (score 0):

`Build -> Build APK`. That should fix it.

Comment: The contents of the settings.gradle are as follows:      `include ':app', ':app2', ':TestNIO', ':TestNDK',':Httpzoid-master'`                 Information:Gradle tasks [clean]
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app2'.
> Cannot evaluate module Httpzoid-master : Configuration with name 'default' not found.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 0.948 secs
Information:1 error
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console